# phpunit selenium2 repeat test not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, laravel-5, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run phpunit with selenium2 for testing my php code.

```
php version : 5.6
laravel version : 5.2
phpunit vesrion : PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

Initial command to start selenium server :

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/bin/chromedriver -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar
```

Mytest.php

```
class Mytest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
public function setUp() {

    $this->setHost('localhost');
    $this->setPort(4444);
    $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com');
    $this->setBrowser('chrome'); // firefox

    //parent::setUp();
}

public function tearDown() {
    $this->stop();

    //parent::tearDown();
}


public  function testcheckhere(){
    $this->url("http://www.google.com");
    sleep(5);
}
}
```

When i run the above code via command line using following command :

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --filter testcheckhere --verbose --repeat 2 --log-junit textexe.xml tests/selenium/MyTest.php
```

I get following error :

```
    PHPUnit 5.7.9 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 5.6.31-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Configuration: /var/www/html/CRM/phpunit.xml

.E                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 9.04 seconds, Memory: 6.25MB

There was 1 error:

1) Mytest::testcheckhere
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'lp-0500', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-43-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:165
/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/Driver.php:175
/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase/CommandsHolder.php:100
/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:394
/var/www/html/mycode/tests/selenium/MyTest.php:29
/var/www/html/mycode/tests/selenium/MyTest.php:29
/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:348
/var/www/html/mycode/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:314

ERRORS!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

Also while test is running , chrome browser opens only once during the first test and later on it doesn't try to open it again.

Comment: It seems that selenium server don't know where to find webdriver.

Comment: If you place chromedriver binary file and selenium server jar in the same directory you don't have to specify _Dwebdriver.chrome.driver_ parameter. Try also `$this->setBrowser('*chrome')` with asterix and set your test base url in the _setUp_ method `$this->setBrowserUrl` then in the test just call `$this->url('/');` phpunit will call automaticaly all methods that start with **test** so the --filter argument is unnecessary. These are mine suggestions, but i'm new in this matter. Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

php version : 5.6
laravel version : 5.2
phpunit vesrion : PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Update your PHPUnit version in Xampp folder like:

1- Download the last version of PHPUnit here: https://phpunit.de/index.html
2- Copy “phpunit.phar” in “C:\xampp\php”.
3- In the file: “phpunit.bat.bat”, update the following line: "%PHPBIN%" "C:\xampp\php\phpunit" %* to : "%PHPBIN%" "C:\xampp\php\phpunit.phar" %*

You have version compatibility issue, once your php version and phpunit version will be compatible with eachother then your application will run without issue. Download the ***phpunit.phar*** file version 5.7.26 because it will be compatible with your PHP Version

Also remove your function:

public function tearDown() {
    $this->stop();

```
//parent::tearDown();
```

}

Comment: How does this relate to a selenium test?

Comment: Its PHPUnit-Selenium Library that you are using. You must set up all the versions compatibility to settle down the errors